# How to search an array built with a select multiple in Mongoose/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a search form that relies on a select multiple attribute.

Here is the code for the form.

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
  <select name="q" multiple>
    <optgroup label="Fruit">
      <option value="peach">Peach</option>
      <option value="apple">Apple</option>
      <option value="pear">Pear</option>
    <optgroup label="Meat">
      <option value="chicken">Chicken</option>
      <option value="beef">Beef</option>
      <option value="pork">Port</option>
   <optgroup label="Dairy">
      <option value="milk">Milk</option>
      <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
      <option value="yogurt">Yogurt</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Here is part of the Mongoose Schema.

```
// db.js
var recipeSchema = new Schema({
  user_id      : String,
  name         : String,
  ingredients : [ String ],
  updated_at   : Date
});
```

Here is the search route with its callback.

// routes/index.js

```
exports.search = function(req, res) {

 Recipe.find({ 'ingredients' : { $all: [req.query.q] }, 'name', function(err, recipes) {
 if (err) return handleError(err);
   res.render('./index', { title: "Recipe Book", recipes : recipes});
 });
```

};

If I pass one value `http://yourserver:3000/?q=milk`, all of the recipes that have milk as an ingredient are displayed; however, wtih two values`http://yourserver:3000/search?q=milk&q=beef` nothing is displayed.

View for displaying results

```
.row
  p Welcome to #{title}
  table.table
    thead
      th Name
    tbody
    each recipe in recipes
      tr
        td= recipe.name
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong or why this isn't working.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Completely revising my answer to something correct:

```
console.log(req.param('q'));
```

Calling the .param() function will properly compile the parameters into an array.

Comment: Completely revised my answer to something much more useful.

Comment: Will, thanks for the reply.  I think the issue was that I wrapping the req.query.q in the array symbol [].  It is passed in already as an array.  I say this because console.log(req.query.q) with a single query value search?q=Peach display Peach and with multiple query values search?q=Peach&Apple display the array ['Peach', 'Apple'].

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was that I wrapping the req.query.q in the array symbol []. It is passed in already as an array. I say this because console.log(req.query.q) with a single query value search?q=Peach display Peach and with multiple query values search?q=Peach&Apple display the array ['Peach', 'Apple'].